# Weird UINavigationController behavior

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I am having a bit of trouble with my navigationController in my app. I am using the Kal Calendar component - https://github.com/klazuka/Kal.

I have created the view controller and have go it to appear in the correct position within in my app i.e. Click on a new tab and init the rootviewcontroller as the KalViewController and it sort of loads correctly but the back button is visible on the navBar when it should be the rootView and it is clickable 5 times before going to the true root, it's hard to explain but I have no idea what is wrong.

i have tried it with a table view and clicking on the first element in the tableView takes you to the calendar which works perfectly but this is not what I want/need in the app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have both a `UINavigationController` and a `UITabBarController`. Make sure that the tab bar controller is your “main” view and that there are separate `UINavigationController`s for each view controller in the tab bar. The different tabs’ view controllers should not be in the same navigation controller’s view heirarchy.

Comment: I sort of get what you are trying to say but it seems that's the way I do actually have it set up. Here is a screenshot of the hierarchy for the app: http://imgur.com/Cvm3Y.png. Hope this helps.

Comment: That seems weird a bit. I’m not sure why that last tab bar item is where it is in the heirarchy. Really, this is a bit complex to be doing in Interface Builder; you may be better off coding this.